# NSTimer does not invoke a private func as selector

Tags: swift, access-control

I am working on a gist: [PasteboardWatcher.swift](https://gist.github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/13efd24f027a775ee862) in which I invoked a NSTimer object like this:

```
func startPolling () {
        // setup and start of timer
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("checkForChangesInPasteboard"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

where definition of `checkForChangesInPasteboard` function is:

```
func checkForChangesInPasteboard() {
        // definition continues..
}
```

I don't want to expose function `checkForChangesInPasteboard` to other classes, therefore I want to mark it as private but for some reason when I do so, it throws below exception:

```
-[PasteboardWatcher.PasteboardWatcher checkForChangesInPasteboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If I don't mark it as private it works perfectly.

**Is there any way I can keep this method as private, hiding it from other classes?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*:

“ Declarations marked with the private modifier do not appear in the generated header. Private declarations are not exposed to Objective-C unless they are explicitly marked with @IBAction, @IBOutlet, or @objc as well.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/utTW7.l

So, you can mark your function with `@objc` to get the desired behavior. I just tested this in one of my apps where I had used public visibility because I assumed that Objective-C couldn't see private declarations at all, and it works when marked as private and decorated with `@objc`.

---

I just saw this related question: [Swift access control with target selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056278/swift-access-control-with-target-selectors?rq=1) — basically the same thing but I think yours is phrased in a more general way so not strictly a duplicate.